# Apache error with suEXEC only

Tags: apache-2.2, php, arch-linux, suexec

When I enable suEXEC by following the [tutorial here](http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/12/18/using-suexec-to-secure-a-shared-server/), I am able to get PHP to run over Apache in cgi mode, but when I start trying to use suEXEC I get a 403, and the following error appears in the error log "client denied by server configuration".  The suEXEC log is empty.  How can I get this working?  My ultimate goal is to run fastcgi with suexec, and this error has stopped me at every turn.

The relevant portion of httpd.conf:

```
ScriptAlias /php5-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi
Action php5-cgi /php5-cgi
AddHandler php5-cgi .php
<Directory /usr/bin>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName skylords.com
    ServerAlias  www.skylords.com en.skylords.com lt.skylords.com nl.skylords.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/htdocs

    SuexecUserGroup skylords skylords

    AddHandler php5-cgi .php
    ScriptAlias /php5-cgi /var/http/htdocs/cgi-bin/php-cgi
    ErrorDocument 404 /srv/http/htdocs
    ErrorLog /srv/http/logs/apache_error.log
    <Directory "/srv/http/htdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

File permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 skylords skylords 7207288 Apr  1 06:00 php-cgi
drwxr-xr-x  2 skylords skylords  4096 Apr  1 06:13 cgi-bin
drwxr-xr-x 17 skylords skylords      4096 Apr  1 06:19 htdocs
drwxr-xr-x 11 skylords skylords 4096 Apr  1 06:13 http
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr  1 05:57 srv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do the permissions of your `cgi-bin` directory and PHP fastcgi wrapper script look like? In my experience suEXEC 403 errors are often because the owner/group of the script doesn't match the owner of the `cgi-bin` directory, or the directory above it.

**EDIT:** OK. Not sure what's going on here... the new information confused me a bit :-) Have you tried setting `LogLevel Debug` in httpd.conf, and checking to see what appears in the error_log when you try to load a PHP script in your browser?

Comment: I'm not yet to the fastcgi step yet - still just trying to get php-cgi and suEXEC to work first.  Updated question with the directory and file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

`ScriptAlias /php5-cgi /var/http/htdocs/cgi-bin/php-cgi` should have been `ScriptAlias /php5-cgi /srv/http/htdocs/cgi-bin/php-cgi`. Sorry for the waste of your time.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? Or was this just additional information?